# Changing formatting of CSV output after AHK script is run

Tags: csv, automation, autohotkey

I'm having some issues with my code [here][1] not sure why it outputs my csv in this [format][2], any idea why? The entries should all be on one row but it splits it across two rows. Thanks.

**Input**

```
;// Fileread, test, somefilename
fileread, AddressList, test.csv

IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
ComObjError(false)
IE.Visible := true

loop, parse, AddressList, `n
{
    PostCode := A_LoopField
    IE.Navigate("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=" PostCode)

    ToolTip, Now looking up %PostCode%

    while IE.readyState!=4 || IE.document.readyState != "complete" || IE.busy
        continue

    ; Collect results 1
    Sleep 2000

    ToolTip, ; remove tooltip

    Name_Elements       := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")
    Loop, 1
    {
        Addr_text       := Name_Elements[A_Index-1].innertext

        Latlon_element  := Name_Elements[A_Index-1].parentElement.getElementsByClassName("latlon")[0]
        Latlon_text     := Latlon_element.innertext

        String_Object   := StrSplit(Addr_text, "`,")
        LatLon_Object   := StrSplit(Latlon_text, "`,")

        If (Substr(Addr_text, 1, 2) = "MK")
        {
            Addr := trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . trim(String_Object[3]) . "," . PostCode . "," . LatLon_Object[1] . "," . LatLon_Object[2]
        }
        Else
        {
            Addr := trim(String_Object[1]) . "," . trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . PostCode . "," . LatLon_Object[1] . "," . LatLon_Object[2]
        }

        Filename_text   := Substr(PostCode, 1, 2)
        StringLower Filename_text, Filename_text

        FileAppend,%Addr%`n,%Filename_text%_addresslist.txt

    }
}
IE.quit()
```

**Output**

```
Levens Hall Drive,Westcroft,MK4 4FL
,52.003,-0.798
Slatepits Croft,Olney,MK46 5EF
,52.163,-0.708
Water Eaton Road,Water Eaton,MK2 2RD
,51.99,-0.728
Southern Way,Hodge Lea,MK12 5EG
,52.054,-0.811
Saxon Street,Stantonbury,MK13 7BX
,52.067,-0.776
Tongwell Street,Brinklow,MK9 2ZQ
,52.032,-0.692
,,MK17 0FE
,,
Bury Street,Green Park,MK16 8EU
,52.086,-0.726
```

**Desired Output**

```
Levens Hall Drive,Westcroft,MK4 4FL,52.003,-0.798
Slatepits Croft,Olney,MK46 5EF,52.163,-0.708
Water Eaton Road,Water Eaton,MK2 2RD,51.99,-0.728
Southern Way,Hodge Lea,MK12 5EG,52.054,-0.811
Saxon Street,Stantonbury,MK13 7BX,52.067,-0.776
Tongwell Street,Brinklow,MK9 2ZQ,52.032,-0.692
,,MK17 0FE
,,
Bury Street,Green Park,MK16 8EU,52.086,-0.726
```

Comment: @MCL - apologies... is the above ok? Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `loop, parse, AddressList, \`n, \`r`. It omits the *carriage return* from Windows files.

Comment: @MCL - wow thanks, it was that EASY?

Comment: I would still recommend using an appropriate library for CSV creation, [this one](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/51681-csv-library-lib/) for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows text files often have a *carriage return* `` `r `` as an additional line delimiter, hence the files look like `` Line 1`r`nLine 2`r`n ``.
 `` Loop, Parse, myString, `n `` will split the string at every line break, but leave the carriage return as part of `A_LoopField`. Most editors will interpret a sole carriage return as a line break nonetheless.
In order to get rid of the carriage return as well, `StringSplit` offers the parameter [OmitChars](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm), a *"list of characters (case sensitive) to exclude from the beginning and end of each substring"*.
The only thing you have to change is your parsing loop:

```
Loop, Parse, AddressList, `n, `r
```